# UITableViewCell shows an unexpected blue outer frame

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

Question:

I'm experiencing an issue with a UITableViewCell in my Swift app. The purpose of the code is to change the background color of the selected cell and keep it selected even when interacting with the text view in the right-side view. However, I'm seeing an unexpected blue outer frame around the selected and focused cell. This issue only occurs when running the app on the simulator.

Here are some details:

- There are no errors or warnings displayed in the console.
- The simulator I'm using is the iPad Air (5th generation) in landscape orientation.
- I'm using Xcode version 14.3 and Swift 5.7.2.
- Could you please help me understand why this blue outer frame is appearing and how I can resolve it?

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let splitVC = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let firstVC = MenuViewController()
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        
        splitVC.viewControllers = [
            UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC),
            UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
        ]
        
        splitVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(splitVC, animated: false)
        splitVC.show(.primary)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    private let textView = UITextView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 400, height: 100)
        view.addSubview(textView)
    }
}

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let table: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        table.backgroundColor = .systemGray5
        table.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return table
    }()
    
    private var contents = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]
    private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemMint
        
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(table)
        
        let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: -55),
            table.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            table.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
        ])
        
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contents.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = contents[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath)?.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        }
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

What I tried:

1. When I placed this UITableView in a ViewController without using UISplitViewController, the issue did not occur.
2. When I commented out the code related to manipulating the cell's background color, the blue frame disappeared.

Expected behavior:

I expected the selected cell to have a changed background color without any unexpected blue outer frame.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you see is due to a change in [iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-13-release-notes#UIKit):

> The UITableViewCell class no longer changes the backgroundColor or isOpaque properties of the contentView and any of its subviews when cells become highlighted or selected. If you are setting an opaque backgroundColor on any subviews of the cell inside (and including) the contentView, the appearance when the cell becomes highlighted or selected might be affected.

Apple gives a solution to this, though:

> The simplest way to resolve any issues with your subviews is to ensure their backgroundColor is set to nil or clear, and their opaque property is false. However, if needed you can override the setHighlighted(*:animated:) and setSelected(*:animated:) methods to manually change these properties on your subviews when moving to or from the highlighted and selected states.

Based on the above, a quick solution would be to use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` (which I assume in you already do in the real code).

```swift
final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) { }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? .systemOrange : .systemYellow
    }
}
```

Note that I'm setting the background color for the `contentView` not the cell itself, otherwise it might not properly work.

The `cellForRowAt` method would be then simplified to something like

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = contents[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

Note that I also commented out the `tableView.deselectRow` call, as that would result in the background color to instantly switch back to the non-selected one.